# Gmail prefix creates link that is broken

Tags: email, url, hyperlink

I have created an email template and included a button that links to my site.

When clicking on the button through Thunderbird the links work fine.

But when I click on the link directly through gmail it gets a prefix that breaks the link.

For example:

By left clicking through thunderbird I get to:
 `https://www.example.com`

By left clicking through gmail I get to:
 `https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&q=https://www.example.com`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was using path.join to concatenate the strings that would create the final url and by doing so path.join escaped some "/" characters.After removing path.join and making simple string concatenation everything worked.